# CDN Support for bundling

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cdn

Is there CDN Support for bundling in asp.net MVC4 ?

For example I don't want to host my own version of jquery locally and i would like to use Google CDN.

Comment: Have a look at `Using a CDN` on this article [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will have to build your own CDN. You could have a dedicated domain that will host all your bundled scripts served throughout an ASP.NET MVC 4 application. This way all your applications could reference the static resources from this CDN. But don't expect to be able to upload your custom scripts on Google CDN any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Read this post which shows how you can set the CDN path of your bundle as well set a fallback expression in case the CDN goes down
http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2012/10/20/new-web-optimization-pre-release-package-on-nuget/